# guardar array de inputs en laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

```php
//comienzo de codigo malo
$precio_ = $request->input('precio_');

$j = count($precio_);
for( $h=0; $h<$j; $h++ ) { 
    $compras = new Compras;
    $compras->CompraprecioUnitario = $precio_[$h];
    $compras->save();
}

$cantidad_ = $request->input('cantidad_');

$c = count($cantidad_);
for( $i=0; $i<$c; $i++ ) { 
    $save = new Compras;
    $save->cantidadComprada = $cantidad_[$i];
    $save->save();
}

//codigo bueno
foreach (session ('productos_add') as $key=>$Productos) {
    Compras::create([
        'productos_id'=>$Productos['codigo_producto']
    ]);
}
```

vista

```html
<td> 
    <input type="text" id="cantidad_{{$cont}}" name="cantidad_[]"  class="inputcantidad form-control" onchange="calculate(),validatecantidad(this)" placeholder="cantidad" required="" >
</td>
```

```
array:5 [▼
    "_method" => "PUT"
    "_token" => "TkjSIyx2C2L6Vi8cX0FqOGik1P9r0gkykN07d8f9"
    "proveedor" => "32232323"
    "cantidad_" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "2"
    ]
    "precio_" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "2
    ]
]
```

Estoy tratando de acceder al campo cantidad_ y precio_ en las 1eras lineas de código. Hice dos intentos de guardar el campo *cantidad* sin mucho éxito: en uno lo realice con metodo foreach y el otro un simple for y ninguno con exito.
Sale este error

> Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario_max-copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 886

este es mi ultima solucion la adjunto en foto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como logro ahora que me muestre todo en un insert solo muestra 1 de los 2 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'cantidadComprada' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `compras` (`productos_id`) values (13), (12))

Comment: Léete el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Son 2 minutos de lectura y así aprenderás como contribuir con la comunidad y a formular tus preguntas para que tengan mejor aceptación, y de paso te regalan una medalla!

Comment: No se si es buena idea partir la linea de `form-control` en el html, no estoy seguro si eso puede estropear algo, quizas no, pero no deberia partirse asi.  Luego no se apenas nada de laravel, pero creo que el `dd` se usa para depurar codigo, y tu lo estas intentando poner dentro del array `$cantidad[]` en tu "codigo malo" como un elemento más no se porque. Sácalo al menos de alli que no creo que pinte nada y dejalo en la siguiente linea en todo caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para guardar variables tipo `array` en una base de datos puedes utilizar el método `insert()` ([Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements))

En tu código primero deberías hacer la validación de los datos que contenga `$precio_` (Voy a suponer que ya lo haces porque no se muestra en tu código)

Suponiendo que los datos de $precio_ ya están validados lo que puedes hacer es:

```
Tabla::insert($variable);
```

Explicación: `$variable` Puede ser un arreglo de arreglos (Los podemos llamar elementos) donde cada elemento tiene los datos de cada columna, en este caso puedes insertar directamente `$variable`, por ejemplo (Muestro la composición de $variable, tiene un arreglo de elementos):

```
$variable = [['columna_1' => 1,
             'columna_2' => 2,
             'columna_3' => 3,
             'columna_4' => 4,
            ],
            ['columna_1' => 5,
             'columna_2' => 6,
             'columna_3' => 7,
             'columna_4' => 8,
            ]];

Tabla::insert($variable);
```

La ventaja de hacer lo anterior es que en una sola línea de código puedes insertar muchos elementos (Por ejemplo, podrías utilizarlo en la parte donde pusiste `// código bueno` en lugar del `foreach`

Otra opción es escribir los valores de cada columna, por ejemplo

```
Tabla::insert([['nombreColumna1' => $variable1, 'nombreColumna2' => $variable2],
               ['nombreColumna1' => $variable1, 'nombreColumna2' => $variable2]]);
```

Explicación: Con esta opción escribes entrada por entrada, por lo que si quieres escribir más de una entrada tendrías que hacerlo de la forma que mostré  en el ejemplo anterior. Esto lo utilizas cuando quieres hacer entradas pero tu `$variable` no tiene los valores de todas las columnas

Recomendación: Asegúrate de que tu variable (En tu código sería `$precio_`) tenga todos los valores para cada columna de tu tabla (O podrías crear una nueva variable con todos los valores de cada columna para usar el ejemplo 1) De esta forma podrías utilizar el primer ejemplo `Tabla::insert($variable);` e ingresar todo tu arreglo en una sola línea de código

La ventaja de utilizar `Tabla::insert($variable);` sería que el número de interacciones que haces con tu tabla se reduce, por ejemplo, en el `foreach` que haces (Mostrado a continuación) cada ves que ejecutas `create()` haces una petición a tu base de datos, si son 10 elementos no habrá problema, pero si son 5000 ó 10000 entonces se va a tardar mucho en hacerlo

```
foreach (session ('productos_add') as $key=>$Productos) {
    Compras::create([
        'productos_id'=>$Productos['codigo_producto']
    ]);
}
```

Para concluir y aterrizando la explicación a tu código:

Te recomiendo que crees un arreglo que tenga la información para todas tus columnas (Suponiendo que `$precio_` ya lo tiene)

```
Compras::insert($precio_);
```

Si quieres hacerlo línea por línea entonces podrías hacer algo así:

```
foreach($precio_ as $p){
    Compras::insert(['CompraprecioUnitario'=>$p]);
}
```

Existe otro método `insertOrIgnore` que funciona casi igual, la única diferencia es que ignora los errores que podría haber en las entradas de datos, por ejemplo si tuvieras valores repetidos y estas intentando escribir a una columna con valores únicos, ignoraría el duplicado y continuaría con los siguientes valores

Comment: pues lo unico que varia de mi codigo es el inset vs create, pero aun asi no me guarda los valores, me guarda los de un foreach y hace caso omiso el otro insert

Comment: ya y como logro insertar dos array en una misma consulta, osea fucionarlos, ver codigo de pregunta , esta actualizado

Comment: Buen día, me parece que no has intentado lo propuesto en la respuesta, ni leído la documentación que también agregué acerca del `insert()`. Para agregar más de un arreglo donde cada uno es una columna diferente entonces se haría así `Compras::insert(['CompraprecioUnitario'=>$p, 'SegundaColumna'=>$q]);` Pero no sería eficiente. Crea un arreglo de arreglos como está explicado en la primera parte de mi respuesta y luego utiliza insert `Compras::insert($todosLosDatosDeTodasLasColumnasEnUnArreglo);`

Comment: necesito 2 arreglos ya que de una manera traigo cantidad y precio y de la otra traigo id nombre y codigo, es posible fucionarlos?? para luego insertarlos en la consulta insert

Comment: Buen día @LuisFelipeBarrosBustos, te recomiendo crear otra pregunta para ese problema. Al hacer una pregunta por publicación permite a otros usuarios encontrar la solución a sus problemas más fácilmente. En este caso la pregunta sobre como guardar `arrays` en una base de datos ya ha sido respondida. Crea una nueva pregunta y ponla aquí para que pueda ver el link y con gusto te ayudo con el nuevo problema. Saludos

Comment: @LuisFelipeBarrosBustos, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: Hola como seria para actualizar campos seria algo como Compras::upsert($insert_schedule); pero como se yo los id a afectar

Comment: te dejo la continuacion de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/517130/como-actulizar-o-hacer-update-con-la-sentencia-upsert-laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

No he utilizado la forma que realizas tu, pero te recomiendo hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

En tu código veo que esto $compras->cantidadComprada => $cantidad_[$i], lo ingresas en un array cantidad no se porque, eso te puede estar provocando el error debido a que no se asigna correctamente el dato y a la hora de tener en tu BD ese campo como not null siempre te generará ese error.

```
foreach($cantidas as $ind=> $cant)
{
  $compras=new Compras();
  $compras->cantidadComprada => $cant;
  $compras->save();
}
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario_max-copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 886

Comment: si no lo guardo como array sale ese error que esta en la respuesta anterior

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar el contenido de una serie de inputs como un array,
por ejemplo tengo un listado de productos y cada uno tiene un input para indicar su stock. Es decir se genera un formulario con un número indeterminados de inputs de entrada para stock, uno por producto, algo así (en Blade):

```
<form action="{{ route('loquesea') }} method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf

    <ul>
    @foreach ($products as $key => $product)
        <li>
            <strong>{{ $product->name }}</strong>

            <siv class="form-group">
                <label for="stock_for_product_{{ $product->id }}"></label>
                <input name="stock[]"
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                    step="1"
                    id="stock_for_product_{{ $product->id }}"
                    value="0">
            </siv>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
<form>
```

Aquí lo importante es como se nombra al *input* para introducir el stock de cada producto, como un array: `stock[]`

En tu controlador tienes un array con los stocks, uno por producto, su valor es 0 por defecto.
Puedes verlo así:

```
dump($request->stock);
```

Si usas validaciones en un ***form request***, una regla que te valdría seria:

```
[
    stock => 'sometimes|array',
    stock.* => 'integer|min:0',
]
```

He puesto *sometimes* en la primera línea, por si en el formulario no hubiera ningún producto (tampoco llegaría stocks en la *request* en este caso).
La segunda línea permite validar el tipo de contenido de cada posición dentro del array.

También podrías usar un array asociativo, vinculando cada stock a la ID del producto:

```
<input name="stock[{{ $product->id }}][]"
    type="number"
    min="0"
    step="1"
    id="stock_for_product_{{ $product->id }}"
    value="0">
```

En este caso la validación podría ser:

```
[
    stock => 'sometimes|array',
    stock.* => 'integer|min:1|exists:products,id',
    stock.*.* => 'integer|min:0',
]
```

Se añadió una validación para las IDs de producto en este caso: valida que se usen IDs que se encuentran en la tabla "products".

En el controlador, lo mismo, para ver el dato:

```
dump($request->stock);
```

Si bien en el primer caso accederías al valor de stock para cada producto corriéndolos en el mismo orden en que se encuentran los productos que enviaste a la vista, en el segundo puedes usar directamente las IDs de los productos para tratar de obtener su stock.

> Editado

Para guardar los datos del array en base de datos usar un bucle que recorra el mismo, p.e. un modelo *Eloquent* de nombre "Product" usando el segundo supuesto: *usar un array asociativo, vinculando cada stock a la ID del producto* (los productos ya existen, se va a proceder a una actualización, en la tabla *products* existe el campo "stock" para el tipo de dato esperado):

```
foreach ($request->stock as $productId => $stock) {
    if ($product = Product::find($productId)) {
        $product->stock = $stock;
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sale este error

Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario_max-copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 886

Comment: en que parte sale como lo guardas?porfavor modifique su respuesta