# como actualizar con la sentencia upsert laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $carrito=session ('productos_add');
    $cantidad_ = $request->input('cantidad_');
    $precioUnitario_ = $request->input('precio_');
   
    
for($count = 0; $count < count($cantidad_); $count++)
{
    $data = array(
            'cantidadComprada' => $cantidad_[$count],
            'compraPrecioUnitario'  => $precioUnitario_[$count],

          );

    $insert_schedule[] = $data; 
 }
   $Variables = Compras::select('id_compras')->orderBy('id_compras', 'DESC')->take( 
    count($cantidad_)+count($precioUnitario_))->pluck('id_compras');
```

lo que quiero hacer es actualizar esos 2 campos cantidad_ y precio_ que lo contiene un array insert_schule lo que intento es con **Compras::upsert($insert_schedule);** nose como donde colocar $variables? que es la contenedora de los id_compras

Comment: Intenta redactar un poco mejor, la verdad no entendi

Comment: lo que intento es actualizar campos ocupando mis variables y mis array ocupando la sentencia upsert

Comment: El problema es que el titulo está mal, actualizar y update son lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dentro del array data debes incluir el id para poder indicar que registro modificar

Esta seria la estructura

```
Compras::upsert([
    ['id_compras'=> 1, 'cantidadComprada' => 30, 'compraPrecioUnitario' => 40],
    ['id_compras'=> 2, 'cantidadComprada' => 30, 'compraPrecioUnitario' => 40]
], ['id_compras']);
```

Comment: como seria con mis variables, porque hice lo mismo pero con insert y me resultó